# Xamarin iOS HttpClient Timeout doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, timeout, httpclient

At some point we found all the requests in our app have timeout of 60 seconds on iOS though we set the default value for the HTTP framework we use as 3 minutes. I tried the following piece of code to figure out if it's the library who has an issue:

```
try
{
    using (var http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5);
        await http.GetAsync("https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=70000");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

This code fails with the timeout exception though the timeout is set as 90 sec and the request goes for 70 sec. Turns out it doesn't override the default timeout of 60 sec. The same code works well on the fresh project.

In the project file we have `<MtouchHttpClientHandler>NSUrlSessionHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin's `NSUrlSessionHandler` uses the **default** `NSUrlSessionConfiguration` if you are not creating your own instance of the `NSUrlSessionHandler` and providing a custom `NSUrlSessionConfiguration` in its .ctor.

The default `NSUrlSessionConfiguration` timeouts are set to 60 seconds in iOS.

So in your Xamarin.iOS application project, open the AppDelegate.cs and set the default session timeout parameters within the `FinishedLaunching` override.

```
NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration.TimeoutIntervalForRequest = 90.0;
NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration.TimeoutIntervalForResource = 90.0;
```

> timeoutIntervalForRequest
>
> ```
> The timeout interval to use when waiting for additional data.
> ```
>
> timeoutIntervalForResource
>
> ```
> The maximum amount of time that a resource request should be allowed to take.
> ```

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/timeoutIntervalForRequest

Comment: I'll try, thanks. Though it doesn't explain why the same works for the fresh project.

Comment: Are you assigning that the HttpClient use NSUrlSessionHandler in that new iOS project? You can look at Xamarin's `NSUrlSessionHandler` code, they do not alter the default NSUrlSessionConfiguration parameters and HttpClient options are not "passed through" as changing the *default* parameters would not be very "polite".

Comment: Sure. Both use it.

Comment: As the value may be set globally, I'm thinking if one of our other 3rd party dependencies could reset it...

Comment: @SergeyMetlov That is possible, you can always provide your own `NSUrlSessionConfiguration` in the .ator to `NSUrlSessionHandler`.

Comment: The documentation of `NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration` in Visual Studio  is "A copy of the default session configuration" meaning (to me) that everything you do to this instance (even if its properties had `set;`) will change nothing;

Comment: @Marc_Alx See "Types of Session Configurations" : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration