# HttpClient getting timed out even after setting Timeout.Infinite

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

i am using `HttpClient` to fetch the data from the server in `Xamarin Forms` using following code

```
public  Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendData(String url,String jsonData)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var jsonContent = new StringContent(jsonData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

            return  client.PostAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative), jsonContent);
        }
    }
```

Here i have used `Timeout.Infinite` as webservice is taking around 4 mins to return the response but although i have set the `Timeout.Infinite` app is throwing `Operation time out` exception. I tried with the various timeouts as well like  `240000ms`  but still getting operation timeout.

However, when i try to fire the same request in postman it is working but yes returning the response after 4 mins of time. As it is a third party api, we can not change anything there.

can anyone please suggest how can i forced the `HttpClient` to hold more for the response.

Detail exception i am getting

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+<RunWithTimeoutWorker>d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000c5] in <3e9b3e26c4694baab3f689687ad40612>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00020] in <3e9b3e26c4694baab3f689687ad40612>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x0041d] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x00478] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <25ebe1083eaf4329b5adfdd5bbb7aa57>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at SignodeMSA.WebService.HttpService+<sendData>d__13.MoveNext () [0x0009c] in D:\VsualStudioWorkspace\SignodeMSA\SignodeMSA\SignodeMSA\WebService\HttpService.cs:141 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at SignodeMSA.WebService.RestApi+<sendDataSimple>d__96.MoveNext () [0x000b3] in D:\VsualStudioWorkspace\SignodeMSA\SignodeMSA\SignodeMSA\WebService\RestApi.cs:199 }
```

Comment: Is this issue on Android or iOS? Are you using AndroidNativeClient?

Comment: It occurs on both the platform m using this in xamarin forms not using AndroidNativeClient

Comment: check this https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/

Comment: this is to handle when user is sending request with a huge chuck of block and my problem is with the response

Comment: @Hunt For iOS use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229363/4984832

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description of the 'Operation time out' exception.

Comment: `An error occurred while sending the request` is the exception and inner exception says `operation has timed out`

Comment: @SushiHangover do you have any fix for Android

Comment: @Hunt Somewhere I do, do not remember it off top of my head, I'll have to look.... Assuming that worked for iOS?

Comment: @SushiHangover i checked for iOS and it did not work

Comment: @Hunt If that did not work, then you have a problem elsewhere, like the OS closing the connection, the cellular/wifi network, etc...

Comment: Well we have full access of network and we tried it over wifi and cellular network too

Comment: Can you give us the actual classes of the exceptions? Not their description.

Comment: @ThomasDeWilde see my edit

Comment: I haven't looked into the exceptions in details, but in the mean time - here's an absurd suggestion. The HttpClient is meant to be created once and reused. Take the HttpClient out of the using statement, and define a single HttpClient in your SignodeMSA.WebService.HttpService class. Give it a try if you will.

Also, how many requests are you firing?

Comment: well initially it was like that only for each request i was creating new HttpClient but the result was same hence i tried using block. I am just firing single request

Comment: @SushiHangover i tried your iOS configuration with `NSUrlSessionHandler` and it worked but the moment i switch to other app or i lock my screen the connected get interrupted, do you have any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried following code for Android and iOS and it seems working and can wait little longer on socket while fetching data using webservice

in `Xamarin.Android` following code is used and exposed it using `DependencyService`

```
 public HttpClientHandler GetHttpClientHandler()
        {

            Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler http = new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler();
            http.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);   


            return http;
        }
```

in `Xamarin.iOS` following code is used and exposed it using `DependencyService`

```
HttpMessageHandler IHttpHandler.GetHttpHandler()
{


    NSUrlSessionConfiguration sessionConfig = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
    sessionConfig.TimeoutIntervalForRequest = 300;
    sessionConfig.TimeoutIntervalForResource = 300;
    sessionConfig.WaitsForConnectivity = true;


    NSUrlSessionHandler sessionHandler = new NSUrlSessionHandler(sessionConfig);

    return (sessionHandler);
}
```

*Note : in case of iOS it will return `HttpMessageHandler`*

Usage in `Xamarin.Forms`

```
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient(DependencyService.Get<IHttpClientHandler>().GetHttpClient());
```

However, there is one catch over here , in case of iOS if app is fetching the data using HttpClient and if user locks the screen by pressing the lock button in iPhone then the service gets immediately interrupted and throws `Connection Interrupted` and socket gets closed. if anyone could find any solution to this then feel free to post

Comment: Thanks @Hunt for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the InfiniteTimeSpan from the System.Threading.Timeout namespace.

```
client.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
```

I'm using it on my Xamarin projects, and it appears to be to working fine.

Comment: I tried the same options as well `client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan` but no luck