# HttpClient seems to be ignoring the Timeout property

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to load a large amount of data from a server by returning `MultiPartContent` in the response. However, during the `HttpGet` method the timeout value I am setting is being ignored. I am trying to set a longer timeout as waiting in this situation is OK.

I have tried various Timeout values between 10 minutes to 2 hours. Realistically the user will only have to wait ~5 minutes the first time they use our app and all other times it will be less.
I have also tried storing a reference of HttpClient to ensure that api.HttpClient isn't re-creating the HttpClient object each time.

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
var progress = new ProgressMessageHandler(handler);
var api = APIHelpers.GetSession(progress);

progress.HttpReceiveProgress += (e, args) => ProgressChanged.Invoke(e, new SyncEventArgs(GlobalEnums.SyncStage.Downloading, args.ProgressPercentage * 0.01f));

api.HttpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

var downloadUri = BuildURI();
var response = await api.HttpClient.GetAsync(downloadUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

I would expect the application to wait for 10 minutes before throwing a Timeout exception, however the exception is being thrown after 100 seconds (i believe that is the default value?).
Checking the `HttpClient.Timeout` value after it is set does show that it was set correctly.

The `APIHelpers.GetSession()` method returns an object of our API with authorisation headers created. The `HttpClient` object is accessible via an inherited class. This is created by Swashbuckle and Swagger. I have used the `api.HttpClient.Timeout = x` this way before with success so I don't think this is the issue. It seems to be specific to this scenario in particular.

The exception thrown:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32 timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts) [0x000f8] in <a1ab7fc4639d4d84af41d68234158b1c>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00019] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1200 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <939d99b14d934342858948926287beba>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x003d1] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/MonoWebRequestHandler.cs:499 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0046a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/MonoWebRequestHandler.cs:503 
  at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<SendAsync>b__1 () [0x000ad] in <6a6c837cafbb4f1faffaba1ff30ca4e3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00150] in <6a6c837cafbb4f1faffaba1ff30ca4e3>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00087] in <19af20e76ce04547b3fc150a0f8f2d47>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:281 
  at ...
```

EDIT:
I'm just adding some additional things I have tried in an attempt to solve this.

1. I have tried using the DependencyService in Xamarin.Forms to get native `HttpClientHandlers` and `HttpClient` objects for each platform where I can set the timeouts per platform instead of relying on `Xamarin.Forms` to translate it for me. This had the exact same result.

```cs
public HttpMessageHandler GetHttpHandler(double timeoutSeconds)
{
    var sessionConfig = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
    sessionConfig.TimeoutIntervalForRequest = timeoutSeconds;
    sessionConfig.TimeoutIntervalForResource = timeoutSeconds;
    sessionConfig.WaitsForConnectivity = true;

    var sessionHandler = new NSUrlSessionHandler(sessionConfig);
    return sessionHandler;
}
```

2. I have tried creating a new `HttpClient` object just for this API call but with no luck here either. (This replaces `Apihelpers.GetSession()` in my code)

Comment: How is the `api.HttpClient` property defined? Is it perhaps creating a new `HttpClient` each time it's accessed?

Comment: Also, you said "Timeout exception", but `HttpClient` throws a `TaskCancelledException` when the timeout is reached. Is that the exception you're seeing?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I wrote in my original post that I have already tried stored the HttpClient object to make sure it wasn't recreating it each time and that didn't work. I have edited my post to include the exception

Comment: Which paltform? iOS or|and Android?

Comment: @SushiHangover Both iOS and Android have the same issue. The above exception is from iOS though

Comment: @LPQ For iOS, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229363/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover Thankyou but i already tried this as I said above in my edit part 1

Comment: @LPQ ? You need to change the DefaultSessionConfiguration, that is not what you described in your edit.

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry, i just added the code to my post edit part 1. Would this not be accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: If you still can't solve the problem, you can open a free Xamarin support case here with a test project: [xamarin-support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hi Jack, I can do. I think i found the cause of the problem was the Handler classes i was using for progress. If i use the HttpClient object without passing in any handlers it works fine. (Although I can no longer get progress!). I think passing in the handlers is causing the HttpClient to initialise as an older version on the devices perhaps with the Timeout bug that used to exist?

Comment: I can't make sure if passing in the handlers will cause the problem as I haven't run your code. You can get more help in the above link or open an issue in Github.

Comment: You can also share a test project here and we will do some test:).

Comment: I just test this problem in the latest Visual-Studio(16.3.1) and it works on my side with `new HttpClient(new ProgressHandler())`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT did you just test in standard .net or did you try this with Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: I test it with Xamarin.forms.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT
Hmm okay. I'm guessing there is another update since i created this post. Perhaps for the release of iOS 13 that might be addressing the issue?
Did you try for Android and iOS or just UWP?

I'll give it a try myself as soon as I can

Comment: I test it in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [known issue in both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/388530/httpclienttimeout-values-set-above-default-100-sec.html) that HttpClient.Timeout values greater than 100 seconds are ignored. This is because the underlying native http clients have a timeout set to 100 seconds, so this times out before the .NET HttpClient times out when the HttpClient.Timeout value > 100 seconds. This should be fixed in all of the latest stable versions, so make sure you are updated. If you are using Visual Studio 2017, you won't have the fix, you will need to get VS 2019 for the fixes.

Comment: Thanks, But I am already using the latest version of Xamarin and the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 already!

Comment: Could you be hitting a server timeout? If the server timeout is shorter than the HttpClient timeout, then the HttpClient timeout will never get a change to fire.

Comment: It isn't this because when i use just new HttpClient() it works fine and a timeout of 10 minutes works. 
If i use new HttpClient(new ProgressHandler()) then it ignores my timeout setting. The issue seems to lie with the ProgressHandler

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in my Xamarin Android project. Resolved it by changing HttpClient implementation to Android in the Project properties as below:
[image]